# angular6 not working locally after sever side render setup

Tags: angular, typescript, server, server-side-rendering

After successfully setting up the server side rendering in angular6, It's building and running as SSR, then the application stop working as a basic app, basically I would like to run my angular6 app as `npm run start`, however, when I ran this command I got this error and seems no documentation related.

The app builds and serve as server-side rendering, but not as a regular app.

This is the error I get:

> ITWS08:A6-Test-3-SSR CC$ npm run start
>      angular@6.0.0 start /eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR
>      ng serve
>
> Could not determine a single project for the 'serve' target.
>     Error: Could not determine a single project for the 'serve' target.
>      at ServeCommand.getProjectNamesByTarget (/eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:175:19)
>                         at MergeMapSubscriber._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect.pipe.operators_1.concatMap
>   [as project]
>   (/eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:50:43)
>                         at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:122:27)
>                         at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:112:18)
>                         at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:103:18)
>                         at TapSubscriber._next (/eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/tap.js:109:26)
>                         at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:103:18)
>                         at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:141:26)
>                         at InnerSubscriber._next (/eclipse/A6-Test-3-SSR/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:30:21)
>                         at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/eclipse/A6-Test-3->SSR/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:103:18)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1
>       npm ERR! angular@6.0.0 start: `ng serve`
>       npm ERR! Exit status 1
>       npm ERR!
>       npm ERR! Failed at the angular@6.0.0 start script.    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>      npm ERR!     /Users/CC/.npm/_logs/2018-05-29T13_46_21_934Z-debug.log
>   ITWS08:A6-Test-3-SSR CC$

Those errors don't show up on the build as server-side rendering

Any ideas?

Seems a problem on the angular-cli.json??

If I replace the angular-cli.json without server-side render configuration, the app works as normal but fail to build SSR

```
            {
              "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
              "version": 1,
              "newProjectRoot": "projects",
              "projects": {
                "angular.io-example": {
                  "root": "",
                  "projectType": "application",
                  "prefix": "app",
                  "architect": {
                    "build": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                      "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                          {
                            "glob": "favicon.ico",
                            "input": "src",
                            "output": "/"
                          },
                          {
                            "glob": "**/*",
                            "input": "src/assets",
                            "output": "/assets"
                          }
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                          {"input": "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"},
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/flag-icon.css"},
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/bootstrap.css"},
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/xmas.css"},
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/styles.css"},             
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/browser-specific.css"}
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                          {"input": "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js"}
                        ]
                      },
                      "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                          "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }
                          ],
                          "optimization": true,
                          "outputHashing": "all",
                          "sourceMap": false,
                          "extractCss": true,
                          "namedChunks": false,
                          "aot": true,
                          "extractLicenses": true,
                          "vendorChunk": false,
                          "buildOptimizer": true
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "serve": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                      "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build"
                      },
                      "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                          "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build:production"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "extract-i18n": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                      "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build"
                      }
                    },
                    "test": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                      "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                          {
                            "input": "styles.css"
                          }
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": [
                          {
                            "glob": "favicon.ico",
                            "input": "src/",
                            "output": "/"
                          },
                          {
                            "glob": "**/*",
                            "input": "src/assets",
                            "output": "/assets"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    "lint": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                      "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                          "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

changing the angular-cli.json to server-side configuration the SSR build perfect and serve as SSR perfect but doesn't works normal, I would like to know how do I make both worlds to work

```
            {
              "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
              "version": 1,
              "newProjectRoot": "projects",
              "projects": {
                "angular.io-example": {
                  "root": "",
                  "projectType": "application",
                  "prefix": "app",
                  "architect": {
                    "build": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                      "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/browser",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                          {
                            "glob": "favicon.ico",
                            "input": "src",
                            "output": "/"
                          },
                          {
                            "glob": "**/*",
                            "input": "src/assets",
                            "output": "/assets"
                          }
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                          {"input": "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"},
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/flag-icon.css"},
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/bootstrap.css"},
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/xmas.css"},
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/styles.css"},             
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/browser-specific.css"}
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                          {"input": "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js"}
                        ]
                      },
                      "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                          "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }
                          ],
                          "optimization": true,
                          "outputHashing": "all",
                          "sourceMap": false,
                          "extractCss": true,
                          "namedChunks": false,
                          "aot": true,
                          "extractLicenses": true,
                          "vendorChunk": true,
                          "buildOptimizer": true
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "server": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
                      "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/server",
                        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
                      }
                    },
                    "extract-i18n": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                      "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "angular.server:build"
                      }
                    },
                    "test": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                      "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                          {
                            "input": "styles.css"
                          }
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": [
                          {
                            "glob": "favicon.ico",
                            "input": "src/",
                            "output": "/"
                          },
                          {
                            "glob": "**/*",
                            "input": "src/assets",
                            "output": "/assets"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    "lint": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                      "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                          "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My problem was the same name of app project and the name of lib project. When I changed the name of the lib the error gone and I can start my project as well with `ng serve`

angular.json:

```
 "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "pn",
      ...
    } 
    "project-name-lib": {
      "root": "projects/project-name-lib",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/project-name-lib/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "prefix": "pn",
      ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep both `"serve"` and `"server"` configs in your `angular.json` file. By that you will be able run app locally as well as server side rendering both. I hope that will solve your problem.